# Prove $\binom{2n}{n}^2 = \sum^{n}_{k = 0} \binom{2n}{2k} \binom{2k}{k} \binom{2n - 2k}{n - k}$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Actually I invented this [formula](https://www.overleaf.com/read/vrgzdctwtdrp#b8e36e). Can someone check if my proof is correct? Or can someone come up with a new proof? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please fully display your mathematical content on this post rather than with a link.

Comment: Or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4042869/694754

Comment: The formula is already known. Please first check the literature before posting. Naming a known identity after yourself is not right.

Comment: As a side-note:  It's great that you discovered that identity for yourself, but I'd strongly advise against ever naming an identity/theorem/theory for yourself.  In my experience, the broader mathematical community responds unfavorably to that.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Thank you for pointing me to the existing questions.